# How can I validate the return value of upload_to callback against the max_length in Django?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model field which is of FileField type and below is how it is defined in the model.

`some_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_me_file_path, max_length=100)`

Here, `get_me_file_path` is a function which accepts the `instance` and the `file name`. This function prepends the relative local path (let us say this takes upto 30 characters) to the `file name` and returns the prepended `file name`.

The `file name` originally comes from the user. The problem is, when the `file name` is between 71 characters and 100 characters long, the database refuses to store the file name into the field (because the prepended filename would become 101 to 130 chars long) and consequently the application throws `500 Internal Server` error.

My question is what is the neat and Pythonic way of validating the string returned by the `upload_to` callback against the `max_length`?

I have a solution which is working for me currently, but it involves hardcoding the max allowed length. Here is my working solution.

In the Django form, I defined a `clean_<fieldname>` function which looks like this:

```
    def clean_some_file(self):
        in_file = self.cleaned_data['some_file']
        if in_file is not None and len(in_file.name) > 70:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Too long file name!')
        return in_file
```

The above solution propagates the error message to the form -> template -> user and work perfectly fine.

The downside is the hardcoded length. If tomorrow, we decide to change the max_length, we need to make sure we update the `clean_some_file` function.

Other option is to implement the validation in `get_me_file_path` function. But potential 2 cons I think (correct me if I am wrong) are a) hardcoding of the length and b) the error would not be propagated to forms.

I have been digging the internet since yesterday with no success.
Your help is highly appreciated.

My environment details:
Python: 2.7
Django: 1.7

**P.S:** 
My form automatically fetches the fields and their definition from the model. The form looks like this:

```
    class SomeClass(forms.ModelForm):
        Class Meta:
            model = MyCorrectModel
            fields = '__all__'
```

Also, when `file name` length is < 70 the application lets the user upload the file.

When name is > 100, Django's form validation automatically kicks in and highlights to the user that name is longer than 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [docs for FileField of Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#filefield),

> Error message keys: required, invalid, missing, empty, max_length
>
> Has two optional arguments for validation, **max_length** and allow_empty_file. **If provided, these ensure that the file name is at most the given length**, and that validation will succeed even if the file content is empty.

All you need is to set an option `max_length` for the field in your form.

```
class SomeClass(forms.ModelForm):
    some_field = forms.FileField(max_length=70)

    class Meta:
        model = MyCorrectModel
        fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields]
        #or fields = "__all__" would also work.
```

Suppose, that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

I added my form definition to the original question, hope it is clear now.

Basically, my form automatically fetches the fields and their definition from the Model.

Comment: Your form is fine. `some_field` should be the field name of the field. That's only needed. Anyway edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks.

Which means the `max_length` is defined in 2 places. One in `models.py` (set to 100 chars). Another in `forms.py` (set to 70).

If in the future, if we decide to change the max_length (in models.py) or the local path (returned by `get_me_file_path`), we will have to change the `max_length` in `forms.py` too (which is I am trying to avoid here).

Comment: I'm afraid, given your circumstances, it's pretty much clear that you do have to define the max length in both places, unless you rewrite the upload_to function to return a more appropriate filename.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Thanks for your help!